# return to line wordpress php (read more)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm actually freaking out because of something I'm sure is so easy but I somehow manage to not find the solution ...

I'm currently working on a WordPress website, and I have a page including all my recent posts, and the articles aren't displayed fully obviously, just a few first words and I have a "read more" link which is defined in wp-content/my_theme/inc/template-tags.php , here is the code :

```
/**
 * Add the read more link to excerpts, except for image attachment pages
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'xsbf_get_the_excerpt' ) ) :
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'xsbf_get_the_excerpt' );
function xsbf_get_the_excerpt( $excerpt ) {

    if ( ! is_attachment() ) {
        if ( $excerpt ) {
            $excerpt .= '&hellip; ';
        } ?>

        <?php $excerpt .= '<a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __( 'Read More', 'flat-bootstrap' ) . '</a>';
    }
    return $excerpt;
}
endif; // end ! function_exists
```

And basically my problem is that I want my **"Read More"** to return to line ^^ as simple as that but yeah as you can guess I've tried `\n` & `<br>`, I guess IDK where to put them.

Don't mind the opening `<?php` & the closing `?>` my problem has nothing to do with it

Comment: What do you mean by "return to line ^^"? Based on your mention of trying "\n" and an actual line break, are you just trying to add a line break (HTML's `<br>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is more a [html](/questions/tagged/html) / [css](/questions/tagged/css) question.)

Depending of the rest of your page, you may want to consider one of the following options:

- Adding a `<br>` tag next to your link;
- Making your link the child of a `div` element and applying the CSS attributes `float: left; clear: left;` on it;
- Applying the CSS attribute `display: block;` on your link.

I think you are mixing the meaning of `\n` and `<br>`. The first one is an Unix new line character while the second one is a HTML line break: `\n` will be rendered as a new line by your browser only if found in a `<pre>` tag, while `<br>` will always be.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, what do you mean my  "next to your link" ?

Comment: By doing something like `(...) . '</a><br>';`, if you want the line break to be _after_ the link.

Comment: hey , well before you awnser i tried this solution (sry i don't even know why i asked my bad :D ) anyway you saved me ! i tried float left clear left but was staying on the same line, then tried to add some margin-top (yeah ik ... but i was pretty desperate :D ) and as you can guess the outcome was disgusting, so i tried display: blokc and TADA ! thank you alot !